# Accessing the MS Access Built-In Bitmap Images

Tags: vba, image, ms-access

I have a VERY large library of VBA code that is used as a Reference for all of my MS Access projects.

I have pretty well finished an ADODB VCR Button class that allows most functions to be controlled by 6 Command Buttons on the form.

I would prefer to NOT have the images used on the buttons to be stored in any of the databases but be able to set the Button Picture to one of the Built-In Bitmaps that appear in the Picture Builder Dialog box.

All of my online searches speak to external image files or storing the images within an Attachment field - which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Is this even possible using VBA to assign the image to each specific button on the loading of the form?

The class has an initialization Sub that receives the Form Object, and then retrieves the Buttons based upon the name of each button. It is at this point I want to set the Picture to the needed Built-In Picture.

Besides searching for about 3 weeks for answers as I work on the Class, I've tried to find multiple ways to set the Picture values, but there appears to be no way to specify which Built-In image to use.

Comment: Sounds like it used to be possible, maybe still. Review https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/734893-where-access-icons-located. If you can get a hold of ADezii, maybe they can provide a clue. Might have to join Bytes.com forum to send PM. I've seen that username on many threads. Maybe more of interest https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons/. And about 3rd-party tool to extract images from DLL https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-10-extract-icons-exe-dll/.

Comment: You could put the images you want in to the newer image gallery. The bult in icons are quite small, and are not all that great anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of, is to have hidden buttons with the built-in images you want, and then change them at runtime using the button's `PictureData` property.

For example, for a hidden button named (what else) `HiddenButton`:

```
VisibleButton.PictureData = HiddenButton.PictureData
```

Comment: Good idea, but wouldn't work. A reference to each button is created in the class, which is within the Library Reference Accdb.<br/><br/>The class set the Tool Tips, contains the Button Events. That's why I'm tying to use Built-In pictures, not ones in a table (though I may have to use a table - I really haven't found a way to place an Attachment Field Image as the Picture on a Button).

Answer (score 0):

You could put the images you want in to the newer image gallery. The bult in icons are quite small, and are not all that great anyway. But a simple "index" into the built in icons don't exist. In fact, when you select a icon, the bitmap is "copied" to the actually button (so a copy of the bitmap is made when you select the button).

The other way? Well, if you look at a button (use the saveastext acForm,"form name", "c:\test\tout2.txt"

You can see the meta data used for that form, and you see this:

```
Begin
            Begin CommandButton
                OverlapFlags =85
                Left =2040
                Top =1500
                Width =1980
                Height =1140
                ForeColor =4210752
                Name ="Command0"
                Caption ="Command0"
                GUID = Begin
                    0xe49b0f036fbef140b250eb300b796a18
                End
                GridlineColor =10921638
                ImageData = Begin
                    
0x2800000010000000100000000100200000000000000000000000000000000000 ,                        
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000b0989070605040e0403020ff ,
0x403020ff403020ff503830ff503830ff504030e0604830806050401000000000 ,
0x0000000000000000000000000000000070585000a08880d0e0c8b0f0fff0d0ff ,

etc. etc. etc.
```

So, you could "copy" the image data you need for the given buttons into say a table, and then at runtime assing the picturedata of a given control to your "saved" list of images in a table.

In fact, I would not suggest nor use "saveastext" as per above, but would drop the 5 or 15 button images you want to use into a form, and then use code to grab the picture data out to a table. Not a great solution, but that's about the only choice you have.

I would also consider using the newer "image" gallery, as then you can use some images that don't like they came from 1990. This would allow you to have/imbed images into the application, and you can then at runtime assign the image to the control at runtime. (or you might have to use a image with click event - I not tested this quite as yet). You can certainly change the image used from the gallery at runtime - and this is VERY little known ability.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a way to save the PictureData value to a table. Then I'm using ADO, DAO was the initial data access.

I can then read the field containing the PictureData and set the value of the property to that field value.

Thank you all for your help.